# Proving $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt n\, \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^n x \,dx=\sqrt{\pi /2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I'm reading the wikipedia article about Wallis' integrals but I stuck at the point where the identity

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt n\, \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^n x \,dx=\sqrt{\pi /2}$$

is proved. The proof:

[image]

to be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals#Equivalence

$(2)$ is the asymptotic equivalence $W_n \sim W_{n+1}$ where $W_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^n t \, dt$.

I do not get the first step: By using $W_n \sim W_{n+1}$, it turns out that $u_n = u_{n+1}$. Why? Can somebody elaborate a bit on this step?

Comment: I think the equation $(2)$ is $W_{n+2}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}W_n$, which directly leads to $u_{n+1}=u_n$.

Comment: Sorry for not getting it, but how?

Comment: $$u_{n+1}=(n+2)W_{n+1}W_{n+2}=(n+2)W_{n+1}\frac{n+1}{n+2}W_n=(n+1)W_nW_{n+1}=u_n$$

Comment: Thank you. I just remarked, there's one last thing I don't understand in the whole proof. I hope I can ask you? At the very ending of the article, one argues by the inequality $$\sqrt n W_{2n+1} \leq \int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-x^2} \, dx \leq \sqrt{n} W_{2n-2}.$$ But $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n W_n = \sqrt{\pi / 2}$, how do I get to $\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-x^2} \, dx =\sqrt{\pi} / 2$ in the last step? Why isn't the $2$ under the root any more?

Comment: $$ \sqrt{n}W_{2n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2n+1}}\sqrt{2n+1}W_{2n+1}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} $$ Same with the right hand side.